# "These and those are idolaters" – what is the problem exactly?

Tags: avodah-zarah, beshalach

According to the Midrash (Shemot Rabbah 21:7, Zohar 2:170b), an angel was accusing Israel and claiming why Hashem should save them and drown the Egyptians: "Just like Egyptians, the Hebrews are also worshipping idols, so what's the difference between them?"

(Somewhat later, the version in Zohar mentions more specifically that is was hard for Hashem to get through the strong Attribute of Judgement.)

What kind of claim is this? Obviously there is a lot of distinction between the two groups. **It sounds like confusing the victim and the perpetrator**!

What is so bad about it that some Jews indeed assimilated and worshipped idols, in a time that they were not really commanded not to do so (besides the prophecy of Aharon)?

Obviously the Jewish camp was full of good middos, incredible potential, inherited from their forefathers, and they were just about to approach Har Sinai to to receive the Torah. Given the fact that there were ample answers possible, what exactly this Attribute of Judgement wanted to achieve with such a seemingly simplistic question?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that worshipping idols is only bad if you are commanded not to do so.

Comment: Granted, it's not a very nice thing to do, but there is still an awful lot of difference between the two camps.

Comment: [Shemot Rabbah 21:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shemot_Rabbah.21.7?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi) says (in Hebrew): "בשעה שיצאו ישראל ממצרים, עמד **סמאל המלאך** לקטרג אותן. אמר לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא: רבונו של עולם! עד עכשיו היו אלו עובדים עבודת כוכבים, **ואתה קורע להם את הים**". i(1) Samael in Midrashim usually means the Satan (accuser) or the minister[ing angel] of Edom/Rome/Chistianity. Why do you call him the Attribute of Judgement? (2) In the Hebrew, Samael only mentioned Israel being idolators, and suggested that they do not merit having the Red sea split for them, on account of that.

Comment: Sorry, that might be an inaccurate quotation. I was reading this lashon from the following piece of Chatam Sofer: https://www.sefaria.org/Chatam_Sofer_on_Torah%2C_Seventh_Day_of_Pesach.21

Comment: Still, here all the details are like I have presented. So it is still a question if such a version of the text exists or is it just a mere mistake.

Comment: Zohar 2:170b indeed has the details like the Chatam Sofer and as I quoted above.

Comment: @Binyomin (As a general rule, if you want a commenter to be informed of your response to them, you should add an `@<user-name>`, for example `@TamirEvan` in my case.) If Chatam Sofer on Torah is your actual source that the question is about, you should edit that (preferably, with a relevant quote) into the question, instead of misleading with the claim that it's from Shemot Rabah.

Comment: Regarding the [Zohar cite](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zohar.2.170b.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi): The Zohar says it was Rahav, the minister[ing angel] of Egypt (אתא **רהב ההוא ממנא דעל מצרים**, ובעא דינא מקמי קודשא בריך הוא, אמר קמיה, ... הא כלהו חייבין קמך) who made the statement, as opposed to Chatam Sofer, who says it was the Attribute of Judgement (מדה"ד שאמר מה נשתנו אלו מאלו). It would make sense that the minister of Egypt would try to equalize Israel's sins to Egypt's, but not the Attribute of Judgement, who should be more impartial and honest.

Comment: @TamirEvan (Thanks for the technical notes!) That is my question. Regardless of which angel, the claim must make some sense! But later the text in Zohar indeed mentions the דין. You're right, I am including the proper sources in my questions.

Comment: The prohibition of worshiping idols was given to Noach and his descendants, so even before the giving of the Torah, the Jewish people should have stayed away from them.

Comment: +1 @TamirEvan; and I would reread it there in the Zohar, and clarify the entities involved, and grasp the overall lesson, for example right after that: And If not for Abraham [midat Chesed] who "got up to pray" at that time (morning); just as it says here "at that time" - which is a big klal, to be magbir Chesed over Din. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%A7%D7%A2_%D7%91